# Razão de perguntas vs respostas no site?

Tags: debate, comportamento

Sou um usuário antigo do stack overflow original onde possuo um histórico de 350+ respostas para vinte e tantas perguntas.

Por razões óbvias, no momento, a versão em português do site está atraindo vários especialistas para responder questões (e com excelente qualidade, estou muito satisfeito com essa fase *Beta*), porém sinto uma grande carência de perguntas.

Estou dedicando bastante tempo para produzir perguntas para o site nessa fase de *Beta* (apesar de pessoalmente gostar bem mais de responder do que perguntar) e acabei invertendo completamente meu perfil (com 7 perguntas e apenas uma resposta no site em português).

Gostaria de saber se vocês também estão sentido que temos uma proporção bem maior de pessoas respondendo do que perguntando, se alguém mais acostumado a responder perguntas acabou se tornando um "perguntador" propositalmente e se a comunidade tem ideias para atrair mais pessoas dispostas a fazer perguntas nessa etapa vital do site.

Comment: O começo é assim mesmo. Isso já teria melhorado se estivéssemos em beta público. De qualquer forma, mande convites para pessoas que você acha que podem contribuir com perguntas.

Comment: O pessoal do Laravel Brasil, que migrou a atividade de seu [fórum](http://forum.laravel.com.br/viewtopic.php?id=1686) para cá, tem gerado diversas perguntas, mas no geral concordo com você que há poucas. Espero sairmos logo para o beta público para isso melhorar, mas ninguém deu previsão oficial quanto à data disso ainda.

Comment: Cade o Gabe? :)

Comment: Quando o beta privado acabar vai mudar. Ainda não ví o site no google, possivelmente por causa do site estar em beta privado. Alguém pode confirmar isto? Gabe?

Comment: Quase ninguém perguntando de Java :..(

Comment: @utluiz e é estranho porque muitas pessoas que fizeram *commit* na proposta tem Java como backgroud.

Comment: Cara, sinto exatamente a mesma coisa. É engraçado, mas faltam _boas_ perguntas

Comment: Estou fazendo a mesma coisa, tentando postar uma pergunta por dia na comunidade do R mesmo já sabendo a resposta. E o interessante é que mesmo sabendo a resposta sempre dá para aprender algo diferente com as repostas dos outros.