# Indicadores da Area 51 e saúde do Beta

Tags: debate, comunidade

Gostaria apenas de chamar a atenção para os [indicadores do Beta na Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539).

Em especial, a galerinha vem respondendo bastante e fazendo um trabalho fenomenal em termos qualitativos.

Porém, segundo os indicadores (e minha [opinião pessoal](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330/razao-de-perguntas-vs-respostas-no-site)) precisamos trabalhar em criar boas perguntas para o site.

- A meta de um beta saudável é de, em média, 15 questões por dia, hoje temos 5.
- Como faltam boas perguntas o pessoal que vem aqui exclusivamente para responder para de frequentar o site...
- Outro ponto para os respondedores natos, não há nada errado em responder uma pergunta que já tenha resposta.

Em especial, mesmo entendendo que esse problema de falta de perguntas vai se resolver com a abertura do site, acho importante ficarmos de olho nesses indicadores.

Dessa forma, ficam os seguintes temas em aberto para discussão:

- Como podemos estimular os participantes do Beta a fazerem mais perguntas?
- Como podemos estimular os participantes do Beta a visitarem mais o site?
- Como podemos incentivar os usuários a votarem mais e serem mais participativos em geral (para formamos a comunidade de base)?

Comment: O principal fator para isso é estarmos em beta privado, sem a participação do grande público. Não acho que a baixa quantidade de perguntas seja uma preocupação imediata. E a forma de melhorar é simples: "simular" um beta aberto convidando o máximo possível de pessoas.

Comment: Nesse ponto estou disparando postagens para alunos e colegas no Facebook e listas de e-mails, tentando convidar mais gente. Mas acredito que tenha o componente de liderança através de exemplo envolvido, se os usuários mais experientes não perguntarem, não vejo os usuários novos fazendo isso.

Comment: Outra dúvida, existem metas para bater antes de abrir o Beta? Eu gostaria de ter um indicativo de performance para saber como estamos andando quando comparados a outros betas. Gabe, nos ajude! (e galera que participou de outros betas, por favor não se acanhe).

Comment: Não é bem o que você está sugerindo, mas se alguém tem dúvidas, quero reforçar que as métricas do A51 não são definitivas. Sites com métricas ruins foram graduados e sites com métricas boas não foram. E de qualquer forma teremos métricas boas com facilidade em alguns poucos meses. Ao contrário da sua percepção, talvez esteja faltando respostas, pelo menos é o que indica a métrica. Ou talvez estejam faltando perguntas mais abertas que permitam mais diversidade de soluções (não listão de respostas). A relação de perguntas e respostas é a única métrica que não sei se melhora.

Comment: Claro que concordo que seria melhor ter mais perguntas ainda. Semana que vem vou tentar fazer um pouco de quality farming pra ver o que acontece :) Me preocupo a falta de participação geral dos mais de mil usuários, que não postem nada, mas pelo menos que votem. Não tem custo votar, não tem como dar nada errado, não vai passar vergonha.

Comment: bigown, concordo com você que as métricas não são definitivas. Você poderia elaborar por que acha que as métricas dizem que faltam respostas? (95% das perguntas respondidas... Só parece faltar um pouco mais de respostas por pergunta).

Comment: É isso, faltam respostas extras para as perguntas. Não precisa ficar na solução única. Ter diversidade de respostas é importante. Eu vejo muita gente apagando respostas boas, ou pelo menos não ruins, que merecem descrédito. Deixa lá, mesmo que não ganhe reputação. Até entendo quando perde. Prevejo o índice de perguntas com pelo menos 1 resposta caindo para menos de 90%, mas isso não é ruim, o SO está abaixo de 80%. Vamos ter problemas que caem na [cauda longa](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauda_longa). A tendência é ser pior aqui. Tem problema que mal tem 1 especialista no mundo p/ responder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Venho acompanhando outros sites também em versão beta, e creio que estamos indo muito bem em comparação! Algumas dessas metas - como X usuários com Y de reputação - aparentemente tem um "prazo" de 90 dias ([exemplo](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43029/amateur-radio)), e isso porque os sites "normais" já entraram em beta público com 1 ou 2 semanas de beta privado (nós estamos fazendo 1 mês).

Algumas comparações:

- `5.6` perguntas por dia

  Esse número é o que mais flutua, pois pega a média das 2 últimas semanas. Já estivemos bem melhor (não só no lançamento, mas por mais algum tempo depois disso), mas não estamos abaixo do "needs some work". É bom lembrar também que muitos de nós estamos **de férias**, de modo que eu só esperaria um aumento na atividade do site pra lá do carnaval...

  Sites que "nos superam" (1ª página somente): [Aviation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation), [Blender](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40377/blender)
- `95%` de perguntas respondidas

  Indicador bom, e consistente com os demais sites (aprox. 50% deles tem indicador melhor, e 50% pior)
- `1,074` usuários no total

  O primeiro que nos supera é o [Space Exploration](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43283/space-exploration), atualmente em **177** dias no beta...
- `62` usuários 200+

  Antes do Space Exploration, apenas dois nos superam, sendo que só o [Pets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44686/pets) está próximo da meta (`101` usuários, `93` dias no beta).
- `2.1` respostas por pergunta

  Creio que estamos indo muito bem nesse quesito: reparei que mesmo as perguntas com auto-resposta normalmente recebem ao menos uma resposta adicional - sinal de que o pessoal está ciente de que é normal uma pergunta ter múltiplas respostas. E embora isso não esteja escrito em nenhum lugar, é bom lembrar também que um número muito **elevado** de respostas por pergunta também pode ser um mau sinal - indicando que as perguntas são por demais subjetivas, sem uma "resposta certa".

  Sites que nos superam (e únicos a já atingir a meta): [Freelancing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37227/freelancing) (`2.7`, `233` dias no beta) e [Open Data](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51674/open-data) (`2.5`, `246` dias no beta).
- `314` visitas por dia

  Nenhum site antes de Pets nos supera, e daí pra frente quase todos também (exceto aqueles que tem algum problema adicional nos outros critérios). Pudera, afinal o beta privado está restrito aos membros... (e ainda assim não sei se esse indicador é confiável quando o número de visitas é baixo)

Não tive muita experiência na Area 51, exceto pela proposta [Gamification](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44478/gamification), já fechada. Mas posso dizer que, ao contrário daquela proposta, esta está cumprindo o seu objetivo principal - ajudar a resolver problemas reais. Por isso, creio que não há muito o que se fazer para estimular mais perguntas/visitas, apenas convidar quem pudermos e aguardar até que o período de férias acabe...

Agora, quanto a estimular a votar, isso sim é um desafio importante! Dos nossos mais de mil usuários, apenas 73 já votaram pelo menos uma vez (nesse mês, uns 20). Por outro lado, não estou sentido falta de "apoio" não - as perguntas e respostas têm tido um número razoável de votos, muitas edições, e as filas de análise e de moderação estão quase sempre vazias. Creio que não há muito a se fazer "pró-ativamente" nesse momento.

Comment: mgibonbr, obrigado por todas as estatísticas.

Comment: Análise muito legal. E é bom reforçar que nossos números estão bem prejudicados por estar fechado (Google não nos vê) além do recesso branco que ocorre todos os anos. E os números já estão um pouquinhos melhores horas depois :)