# Por que (me parece que) o StackOverflow em Português não dará certo?

Tags: debate

Eu tenho a impressão que essa versão do SO não dará certo.

Acho que o profissional de TI com boa base de conhecimento tem inglês suficiente para utilizar a "versão original" já que um conteúdo muito mais rico e mais avançado é encontrado por lá.

Outro ponto, os programadores iniciantes "não estão se importando com o sistema", eles perguntam de qualquer forma, não esperam um tempo hábil para responderem e não voltam para dar um feedback da solução do problema.

Terceiro ponto, seu currículo não está aqui, ainda não existe a cultura de ter um bom perfil para ter uma boa avaliação pelas empresas, então negativar ou ser negativado não tem um peso real.

(Leia abaixo minha conclusão/resposta)

Comment: Legal você deixar a sua opinão sobre o site, tem uma pergunta relacionada já: [Por que um StackOverflow em pt-br?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/671/91). Se tiver interesse entre no [chat do site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) para trocar uma ideias com o pessoa mais ativo, talvez veja coisas boas da versão em português.

Comment: Sua forma de pensar é extremamente negativa. Tem muitos que estão aprendendo e alguns até com certo conhecimento que não sabem inglês, e é ai que o SOPT entra forte.

Comment: Depende do que você considera "dar certo"...

Comment: É só ir consultar o numero de visitas, com o perdão, mas está me parecendo um texto presunçoso sem base nenhuma de dados ou entendimento da comunidade.

Comment: Dar certo no sentido de ser a grande referencia em obter respostas (neste caso específico) em programação.

Comment: Por isso usar a palavra "impressão". Sem base científica.

Comment: @MBecker na sua outra pergunta eu lhe mandei um link que fala justamente disso, acredito que foi falta de atenção sua ao ler http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3851/3635, lá eu explico a questão das idades dos sites. ;D

Comment: O [stackoverflow](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) inglês tem muito mais conteúdo, visto que ele foi criado em 2008. Já o português foi criado em 2013. Isso não significa que ele não dará certo, pelo contrário, ele já está crescendo e ganhando usuários. Veja esse [post](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5524/51124).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu vi o seu incentivo, até concordo mas eu realmente queria me expressar! A final, minha conta ainda está aqui, não está?

Comment: Mas o SO é pra que quer compartilhar conhecimento, disseminar ideias e melhorar as experiências. Tem muita gente que gosta disso. Tem a até gente que tem 892 respostas e nenhuma pergunta(@bacco). Acha que se não fosse bom pra ele, estaria aqui contribuindo?! Minha opinião é: A comunidade é boa e funciona! Sempre que eu puder, vou estar aqui ajudando e aprendendo.

Comment: Nós não estamos livres para perguntar. Minha pergunta é ruim ou degradável, pois existe uma diferença. Uma pergunta ruim não gera tantas discussões, ela acaba sendo ignorada. Mas veja que o marcador está descendo, -7 ou -8 até terminar de escrever. Não deveria ter peguntado.

Comment: Essa é só nossa reação ao seu post. Os votos no meta, geralmente, tem um objetivo diferente dos votos no site principal.

Comment: Não é porque estão te negativando que não devia ter perguntado. Você tem o direito de perguntar. Sua pergunta está ganhando negativos porque tem gente que discorda de você, gente que se incomoda com a sua opinião, etc. Isso faz parte.

Comment: Eu desconfio que a sua pergunta foi negativada devido ao tom meio pesado, para alguns pode parecer como uma provocação ou ser ofensiva (imagino que não seja esse o objetivo), sugiro editar alguns trechos e deixar os principais pontos mesmo não concordando com a comunidade.

Comment: Mas ele já não está dando certo? Com problemas, claro, mas no que ele é pior que a versão em inglês? É menor? Claro. Tem bem menos profissionais de alto nível? Não há dúvidas. Por tudo isso tem uma chance menor de ter um número elevado de ótimas perguntas e respostas? Sim. O quantidade absoluta de porcarias aqui é menor do que lá? Óbvio. E proporcionalmente? Não é muito diferente. Podia ser melhor? Podia. Tem algo melhor em português? Me mostre. Ele é bem útil? Com certeza. Ele me rendeu um reconhecimento pela Microsoft e isso deve indicar alguma coisa? Exato! Minha percepção é outra.

Comment: Rapaz, você está um pouco atrasado, 3 anos para ser mais exato.

Comment: A cada dia que eu entro nesse site, eu vejo que não está dando certo. Por isso que entro quase todo dia, já postei mais de 500 respostas e já solucionei um monte de problemas que tive com base no que achei aqui... Realmente não está dando certo!

Comment: Em breve podemos  ser TOP 5 da rede: http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday

Comment: Eu dei +1 pela abertura do debate.

Comment: Minha bola de cristal diz que a primeira medalha de ouro do tipo [Reversão](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal) do site vai sair para uma das respostas abaixo. E talvez não só uma.

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu também

Comment: Discordo totalmente do autor, só.

Comment: @VictorStafusa seria incrivel :')

Comment: @bfavaretto A tag [destaque] não tem efeito em perguntas com votação negativa.

Comment: Pois é @Victor, percebi. Uma pena, porque o site está escondendo essa discussão.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Parece que era cache.

Comment: Eu ia escrever uma resposta, mas todo mundo já fez isso melhor que eu. Me resumo a dizer o quanto o site me ajudou: um MVP, um emprego em Chicago, vários novos clientes, contratei pelo menos sete pessoas aqui (uma delas é meu sócio hoje em dia), fora os convites para eventos de tecnologia e novos amigos. Por fim, você acha mesmo que nossos currículos não estão aqui? Veja os perfis.

Comment: O cara tem a opinião dele, o qual não concordo, agora negativar o cara só porque ele tem uma opinião que não agrada a maioria, isso sim, é falta de conhecimento, falta de respeito e etc. É a opinião dele. Negativar deveria ter um critério, coisa que não tem. Se não gostei, downvote. Olhando esses downvotes, dá até vontade de concordar com o post.

Comment: @pnet Aconselho você a ler isso:  ["Votos a favor e votos contra no META. O que o voto significa para você?"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4788/20615). Votos no meta não tem o mesmo significado do site principal. Muitas pessoas utilizam apenas para dizer se concordam ou não com a pergunta/resposta. O fato de negativar aqui não significa que é algo ruim, mas sim que algumas pessoas não concordam com a pergunta. Adentrando um pouco mais na pergunta, olhe o [histórico de edições](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/5654/revisions) e veja como estava a primeira versão. +

Comment: Muitos não concordam o que é o direito de cada um. Outros já votaram positivo por gostar do debate, o que também é opinião de cada um. O fato de nem todos concordarem não significa que somos um **"povinho sem critério algum"**.

Comment: @Randrade Não sei se fiz certo mas quis deixar claro qual foi meu texto original. Apenas editei o título porque a frase "Eu tenho a impressão" estava sendo ignorada :)

Comment: @MarcusBecker O ideal seria você deixar somente o texto original e postar a resposta no campo de resposta. A maioria que leu entende o que ocorreu, pois participou de todo o debate. Mas como está todo mundo "feliz", por mim está tudo certo :p

Comment: @Randrade feito :)

Comment: Boas, Pra mim ja deu certo em certos aspectos

Comment: Uso o Stack em português e acho melhor que o em inglês, porque o pessoal todo de lá se ajuda como pode

Comment: Atualização de [2017-11-28](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5655/3635), tivemos em média um aumento de 20% em todos fatores :D

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Primeiro Ponto**

Acho que não podemos generalizar esse fator. Saber inglês é algo fundamental em nossa carreira, disso ninguém possui dúvidas, ter que aprender inglês para sanar suas dúvidas eu acho que não é necessário.

Claro, temos muitos artigos e tutoriais *porcos* em português, mas em que idioma não temos? rsrs

E devemos levar em conta que temos várias pessoas com inglês fluente que preferem utilizar o SOPT. O fato de uma pessoa *saber* inglês, não significa que prefira utilizar.

**Segundo Ponto**

Não existe uma forma de qualificar isso. Olhando o histórico de pergunta de vários usuários podemos ver um crescente aprendizado. No início fazendo perguntas simples e "bobas", mas depois evoluindo e se tornando bons profissionais.

Muitos desses usuários retornam para retribuir a ajuda que tiveram respondendo as perguntas que os mesmos saibam responder.

Quem realmente se importa em aprender, e está iniciando na programação, não sabe o que realmente é bom para fazer, e por isso deve sim perguntar.

**Terceiro Ponto**

Esse eu posso **afirmar** que está totalmente equivocado.

Eu mesmo consegui meu emprego atual por meio do SOpt, assim como muitas outras pessoas aqui do site.

Empresas que não olham o perfil no **Stack Overflow** estão atrasadas, pois as maiores já fazem isso.

Outra prova, [como dito pelo @bigown](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5654/por-qu%C3%AA-o-stackoverflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-n%C3%A3o-dar%C3%A1-certo/5655#comment21461_5654), a Microsoft utiliza este site para premiações. Se isso não é ter reconhecimento, acho que não sei o que é ter.

**Complemento**

Apenas para complementar um pouco, para *abrir* um site novo, o mesmo deve passar por uma **votação** na [área 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). Após, isso é iniciado um beta do site.

[Nesta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/456/20615) você pode ter uma ideia de como era o SOpt no beta. Analisando com os dados da resposta do @GuilhermeNascimento, pode-se ver como evoluímos muito.

Para você ter ideia de como as propostas são analisadas, [havia uma proposta para o Super User em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2482/super-user-em-portugu%C3%AAs-j%C3%A1-era-no-area-51), mas a mesma foi fechada e com isso o novo site não foi para o ar. O motivo da proposta não ter sido aceita, você pode [ver nesta resposta do Tim Post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2545/20615).

Apenas para conhecimento, [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5120/%C3%81rea-51-o-que-%C3%A9-necess%C3%A1rio-para-uma-proposta-entrar-em-beta-teste) pode-se ter uma ideia do que é necessário para abrir um novo site.

Comment: A premiação da Microsoft ocorre também no SOen?

Comment: @MBecker A premiação da Microsoft ocorre por diversos fatores, e ela não divulga para não atrapalhar. Porém, usuários ativos lá que possuem essa premiação também.

Comment: O Brasil, por não ser uma país de terceiro nível, tem muitas empresas atrasadas. Sua empresa ou de outros contratados, é 100% brasileira?

Comment: Acho o segundo ponto importantíssimo e talvez o melhor qualificador. Claro que tem usuários que vão passar a vida toda só sugando, não vão aprender nada. Mas isso é igual no SOen e nada tem a ver com o site, é um ponto negativo pessoal de quem não consegue sequer perceber o que o site pode fazer por essa pessoa. Eu aprendi muita coisa aqui no SOpt mesmo. Claro que eu adoraria que tivesse um Eric Lippert respondendo aqui, mas temos um punhado de gente boa também. Não dá para comparar algo global com algo de nicho, que é o SOpt, mas isso vale para qualquer coisa. Já deu certo!

Comment: @MBecker A maioria das empresas das pessoas que comentei são nacionais, e algumas ainda são estaduais ou municipais (ou seja, só atuam na cidade ou no estado das mesmas).

Comment: @MBecker Editei a resposta com alguns dados que acho interessante, caso queira ver.

Comment: Mas o Gabe deu como certo que esse terá o SUpt :D http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34682354#34682354

Comment: Eu não queria estragar a piada, mas quem ler isso sem um contexto pode achar que é verdade. Não foi bem isso que ele falou, isso virou apenas um brincadeira. Há alguma possibilidade de haver algum site internacional novo "em breve".

Comment: @bigown Eu iria colocar [o comentário dele](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34682304#34682304), mas *vai que...*. Achei melhor deixar assim e atualizar a resposta se tudo der certo. kkkk

Comment: Não sabia que tiveram que "suar tanto" para trazer esse site a vida. Acho que o sistema de pontuação não é perfeito, nem a democracia, mas pode ser o melhor que temos por enquanto. Para os usuários, um filtro, para os  bem pontuados, uma arma. Espero que consigam manter o equilíbrio.

Comment: @MBecker O sistema de pontuação é válido para muitos e inválido para muitos outros. Porém, vem dando certo até então.
Porém, se achar que foi vítima de algo desse tipo, pode sempre sinalizar para um moderador dar uma olhada :p

Comment: @bigown **não me dê uma úlcera dessas!!!** :D

Comment: @Gabe eu não quero saber, eu quero o SUpt!

Comment: Parabéns pela primeira medalha de ouro [Reversão](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal?userid=20615) do site. :D

Comment: @VictorStafusa Vlw :p. kkkk

Answer (score 34):

Muita coisa pra desempacotar nesse post, né... Eu vejo como uma questão com bastante nuância e subtexto. Com diversas respostas "óbvias", tanto para sim quanto para não, e tudo depende de expectativas.

Sempre me foi evidente - e acredito que seja para todo mundo - que o SOpt nunca será do tamanho do SOen. Nós, sob hipótese alguma, chegaremos a ter 10mil perguntas/dia. Esse é o volume do SOen, com uma audiência de 40 milhões de pessoas. E nós não temos 40 milhões de programadores em língua portuguesa. Simples assim.

Nunca foi a intenção ou expectativa da Stack Overflow (a empresa) que esse, ou qualquer outro site internacional, chegasse à esse volume de atividade. Somos meio malucos, mas nem tanto. Nosso objetivo sempre foi outro: levar conhecimento de qualidade à pessoas que não podem, ou não preferem, participar do site em Inglês.

Utilizar o SO (qualquer deles), como você disse, é muito mais do que poder ler o site, entender as perguntas e as respostas. Se uma **comunidade** não existe em torno dele, o site está fadado à irrelevância. E a barreira linguística se torna exponencialmente maior para fazer parte de uma comunidade, do que para apenas consumí-la.

É para isso que o SOpt/ja/ru/es existem. Para fomentar uma comunidade. Para alimentar o interesse, a busca pelo conhecimento, o sentimento de engajamento e de pertencer a um grupo de pessoas que detem um mesmo interesse que você. Apesar das 10 milhões de perguntas, ter criado um ponto central para tanta gente, de língua inglesa, ainda é a maior conquista do SOen.

E é isso que queremos para todos os outros internacionais. Desatrelar o benefício de uma comunidade de uma língua específica. Ninguém precisa ser obrigado a aprender uma língua só para poder se sentir em casa.

Se olharmos *apenas* para os números, me parece claro que o SOpt deu certo. Em 3 anos, somos um dos 10 maiores sites da rede, com apenas metade da idade do resto. Somos maiores, em participação, que o Server Fault. Vamos ultrapassar a marca de 100 perguntas/dia em muito pouco tempo. Somos o site mais rápido - exceto o SOen - a atingir a marca de 10 mil perguntas. Me parece inquestionável que somos um sucesso.

Se olharmos para a questão subjetiva de impacto cultural... A análise obviamente não é tão clara (vide: subjetivo). Mas ainda assim podemos fazê-la.

A cultura de programação no Brasil/Portugal não é tão madura e avançada quanto a Americana. Nosso site não nasceu anunciado por expoentes famosos como Joel Spolsky e Jeff Atwood. Não tivemos pontos centrais de divulgação como o SOen teve. Tudo isso é verdade, e torna nossa caminhada ao reconhecimento mais íngreme.

Mas, em 3 anos, nós *definitivamente* temos sucesso. O número de visitantes recorrentes quadruplicou nos últimos 3 anos: gente que reconhece quem somos. O número de novos usuários, depois de ficar estagnado por um bom tempo, mais que duplicou em 2016: gente que vê valor em ter uma conta no SOpt. O número de visitas não para de crescer: sinal de que estamos, definitivamente, prestando um serviço bom e útil.

Eu sei que esses também são números, então podemos olhar as histórias [neste post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5524). De gente que avançou na carreira, que aprendeu coisa nova, que fez novos contatos, que deu um passo à frente... graças, direta ou indiretamente, ao site.

Não temos como, assim como o SOen, causar um impacto estrondoso e imediato. As circunstâncias são outras, os tempos são outros e até mesmo a plataforma é outra. O que nós podemos, e definitivamente estamos fazendo, é comer pelas beiradas. Nosso jogo é outro, de longo prazo, de insistência e foco.

E não há porque imaginar que não vamos conseguir, enventualmente, ser um farol para a área de programação no Brasil, em Portugal, ou qualquer outro país de língua portuguesa.

Conhecimento de desenvolvimento, assim como qualquer outro, não tem relação com onde você nasceu, ou que língua fala. Acesso à informação, sim. Mas talento, apreço, dedicação... nada disso é especial às pessoas daqui, ou dali.

Afirmar que nosso conteúdo não é capaz de fazer frente ao SOen me parece não levar em consideração o conhecimento **astronômico** de pessoas como o [@bigown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101), [@bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74), [@Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129), [@Luiz Vieira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/73), e literalmente dezenas de outros (boa parte fluentes em inglês, e com "carreira" no SOen - mas que participam do nosso site) que deram respostas profundas, claras, recheadas de informação, por vezes quase canônicas, no SOpt. Para usufruto de dezenas de milhares de pessoas.

Nossa [resposta mais bem votada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2405) foi acessada quase 12 mil vezes ao longo desses 3 anos. Uma resposta que não deixa nada a desejar - e, na minha opinião, superior em abrangência e didática - ao que talvez seja sua [equivalente mais direta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/401684) no site em inglês.

Qual o valor, e o impacto, desse conteúdo na vida das milhares de pessoas que aprenderam com ele? Quantos programadores aprenderam com essa resposta, e quantos usuários agora têm suas senhas armazenadas de maneira muito mais segura e responsável, tudo por causa da nossa comunidade?

O impacto seria o mesmo, se esse conhecimento ficasse atrelado apenas ao subconjunto de programadores com conhecimento suficiente em inglês para ler, e compreender totalmente, a resposta do SOen? Sinceramente, duvido.

**Esse** é o propósito do SOpt. É para isso que trabalhamos, todos nós. Como gerente, acho que ninguém sabe melhor que eu onde erramos, onde definitivamente podemos melhorar, e onde é possível fazer mais. Não acredito que alguém tenha a impressão de que somos perfeitos, ou que um dia seremos perfeitos.

Mas vendo onde essa comunidade já chegou, num espaço de tempo tão curto e enfrentando tanta coisa, eu sei que não estou sozinho quando prevejo um futuro cada vez mais brilhante para o SOpt, cada vez mais útil, cada vez mais conhecido, cada vez mais respeitado.

O "pequeno site que podia". Um experimento, quase sem fundamento algum para existir, que só faz surpreender na sua capacidade de ir em frente e crescer.

Nós nunca seremos tão grandes quanto o SO em inglês. Não é pra isso que irmãos mais novos existem. Tudo que nós podemos fazer é nos tornarmos o melhor que podemos ser: **independentes, fortes e orgulhosos.**

Comment: Mesmo a pergunta e a resposta sendo adaptações da versão em inglês, é bom ver o conteúdo na sua própria língua, onde é mais fácil ter 100% de compreensão.

Comment: @MBecker está entendendo o objetivo. Se o inglês fosse tão fundamental de forma profunda para a área, os cursos superiores seriam ministrados em inglês. Inglês é útil, não obrigatório. Fluência em geral só se pretende um cargo em projetos que envolvam internacionalidade. Conforto é importante para evoluir. Na sua língua fica mais fácil.

Comment: @MBecker Exato. Mesmo que a pergunta e resposta fossem traduções diretas do site em inglês, elas já trariam imenso valor à comunidade. Mas ao fazer mais que isso - atualizando e aprofundando no assunto, ela provê ainda mais valor à quem fala português do que a original é capaz de fazer.

Comment: Só um aparte, aquela resposta é uma adaptação dessa: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/20117 e não equivalente do SOen. Ora veja.

Comment: Eu só queria dizer que ser citado nominalmente pelo Gabe neste post bate qualquer reconhecimento da Microsoft. :)

Comment: (just kidding, Microsoft)

Comment: Parabéns pela segunda medalha de ouro [Reversão](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal) do site. :D

Comment: @VictorStafusa \o Fico feliz que as duas tenham saído nesse post.

Comment: @LuizVieira Eu posso parecer meio tapado, posso até *ser* meio tapado, mas eu gosto de pensar que sei reconhecer gente inteligente. E a minha lista de programador de ponta que participa aqui é bastante extensa. Eu citei vocês, mas deixei de fora tanta gente que é até injusto ter sequer criado a lista `:)`

Comment: "E a barreira linguística se torna exponencialmente maior para fazer parte de uma comunidade, do que para apenas consumí-la." Somente isso já serve pra justificar a existência do SOpt.

Answer (score 25):

Acredito que somos bem mais organizados e procuramos exigir um certo tipo de qualidade das respostas que o SOen, fora que quase tudo o que eu preciso eu encontro no SOpt e o que eu não encontro se tiver no SOen eu tento trazer para cá traduzido e até mais detalhado.

Em Janeiro 2017:

- 60k de perguntas
- 76k de respostas
- 78% das perguntas são consideradas resolvidas
- 42k usuários
- 31k de visitas por dia
- 88 perguntas novas por dia

Em Fevereiro de 2017 (3k respostas novas em apenas um mês me parece uma razoável evolução):

- 62k de perguntas
- 79k de respostas
- 78% das perguntas são consideradas resolvidas
- 43k usuários
- 38k de visitas por dia
- 93 perguntas novas por dia

Os números são bem maiores do que muitos sites da rede internacionais (ao meu ver):

- http://stackexchange.com/sites#questions

Ter 93 novas perguntas por dia (praticamente o mesmo que o *Server Fault*, uma comunidade bem popular) mostra como estamos ativos e ter 38k de visitantes mostra como somos usados como fonte de pesquisas/estudos.

> eu fiquei de olho quase todos os dias no link, variou entre 92 e 93 depois do ano novo e janeiro, talvez após o carnaval suba um pouco mais o número de novas respostas.

---

### Atualização 2017-11-28

- 89k de perguntas (aumento de ~30.3%)
- 109k de respostas (aumento de ~27.5%)
- 75% das perguntas são consideradas resolvidas (**diminuiu** de ~3.8%)
- 71k usuários (aumento de ~39.4%)
- 55k de visitas por dia (aumento de ~30.9%)
- 120 perguntas novas por dia (aumento de ~22.5%)

> **Nota:** as perguntas resolvidas diminuiram, mas isso é devido ao aumento de perguntas ter sido maior que o de respostas, ainda sim o aumento foi quase equivalente, tanto que perguntas resolvidas diminuiu míseros `~3.8%`

Comment: Você tem bons números mas acho que a melhor resposta seria "o tempo dirá". Espero que façam este site ser uma referencia na resolução de problemas com qualidade. Parabéns Guilherme por se mostrar uma pessoa bem ponderada. Abs.

Comment: @MBecker obrigado e seja bem vindo, com união crescemos mais ;)

Comment: oi Guilherme, onde você conseguiu esses dados?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo no link da propria resposta onde eu escrevi: *> Os números são bem maiores que os da média (ao meu ver): http://stackexchange.com/sites#questions* (inclusive hoje os numeros melhoraram 92 perguntas/dia), ou seja **talvez** após todos festividades no Brasil ainda melhore mais :)

Comment: Parabéns pela medalha de ouro "Reversão". :)

Comment: Eu acho que essa resposta merecia um destaque especial, pois ela atende a questões que vão além da pergunta original. Quem sabe uma pergunta mais ou menos no estilo "Quais os medidores de sucesso/eficiência do SOpt? Como eles estão evoluindo? Como se compara com outras comunidades SE?" como sendo candidata à FAQ

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Excelente ideia! Mesmo que a resposta aqui não seja totalmente ideal para isto, pois a "ferramenta" que usei só compara duas datas isoladas, ainda sim se criar um FAQ ou algo semelhante existe essa ferramenta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics para poder acessar dados com maior precisão (se não tiver acesso veja o print: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAjZG.jpg), eu vi a sua sugestão no Meta, no fds vou dar uma olhada geral nisto.

Answer (score 13):

As respostas atuais já contém muitos dados que mostram que a **nossa comunidade** esta crescendo cada vez mais e que esta **dando certo sim**. Então não vou me focar neste ponto e sim em outro ponto citado pelo @MBecker que é o seguinte:

> Outro ponto, os programadores iniciantes "não estão se importando com
> o sistema", eles perguntam de qualquer forma, não esperam um tempo
> hábil para responderem e não voltam para dar um feedback da solução do
> problema.

Não posso dizer que isso não seja verdade, isso acontece aqui no SOpt mas também acontece no SOen e em outros sites da rede StackExchange e acontece muito mais em fóruns e em outros sites estilo Q&A.

Mas isto é motivo para desacreditar ou desistir e pensar que o SOpt não esta dando certo?

É claro que **NÃO**! E eu ainda recomendo que você faça como o @VictorStafusa:

> A cada dia que eu entro nesse site, eu vejo que não está dando certo.
> Por isso que entro quase todo dia, já postei mais de 500 respostas e
> já solucionei um monte de problemas que tive com base no que achei
> aqui... Realmente não está dando certo!

**Eu sou um programador iniciante** e nunca deixo de me importar com o sistema. Eu sempre procuro elaborar perguntas da melhor forma possível e que seja clara e objetiva, dou o feedback da solução do problema e ajudo na moderação do site e mesmo não tendo muita conhecimento ainda para contribuir de forma mais significativa com respostas eu procuro contribuir de outras formas, dando recompensas para perguntas boas que não receberam muita atenção, orientando novos usuários em relação à utilização do site, participando do meta, editando perguntas e respostas e votando para fechar e reabrir perguntas e muito mais. Tudo isso é possível graças ao meu comprometimento com o SOpt e eu sei que em um futuro não muito distante seremos grandes como SOen é agora e o SOen será maior ainda.

## E quem ganha com tudo isso?

Você, eu, e a comunidade de desenvolvedores da língua portuguesa, o Brasil e outros países que tem a língua portuguesa como sua linguá falada. Porque graças a vocês que dedicam seu tempo ajudando outras pessoas aqui no SOpt que alcançaremos um futuro melhor para a a Tecnologia da Informação para as crianças de hoje que serão os programadores de amanha porque terão uma fonte rica, confiável e repleta de informação de qualidade que se chama Stackoverflow em Português!

---

E aí, você ainda acha que o SOpt não vai dar certo?

Comment: Sinto-me honrado por ter sido citado nessa resposta. +1.

Comment: Você foi citado em torno de 11 vezes :)

Answer (score 12):

Cheguei a conclusão de que realmente o SOpt não dará certo. Não dará certo do jeito que eu achei que seria certo, comparando com o SOen.

O SOen está muito a frente em matéria de solução, afinal, a maioria das tecnologias nascem em inglês e chegam até nós com um certo delay. Muito provavelmente sua dúvida já foi respondida lá antes mesmo de você ter se quer perguntado. Mas com base nas discussões nesta pergunta e no que vi e encontrei aqui, vejo que ele já deu certo de uma outra forma, de uma forma brasileira.

Ele é a opção de quem quer perguntar e ser respondido na sua própria língua, por pessoas que tiveram muito mais dificuldade para obter respostas e estão dispostas a compartilhar-las de boa vontade. Por pessoas que preferem 1 opinião ao invés de 100 resultados do Google e quando isso acontece, é muito gratificante. Eu trouxe minhas dúvidas para cá e encontrei respostas incrivelmente relevantes.

Eu realmente me dei o direito de provocar utilizando inicialmente um texto "agressivo", por isso peço desculpas, mas por isso também obtive de vocês respostas tão elaboradas, cheias de emoção, e disso eu não me arrependo. Obrigado a todos por me darem um lugar para perguntar.

Answer (score 10):

Me parece que está a comparar com o volume de dados do SO-en como um parâmetro de definição de "sucesso". Isso não tem cabimento pois o que diz se o negócio é bom ou não é uma simples equação matemática. Em termos contábeis:

```
Entrada - Saída = Saldo
```

Se o saldo é positivo, é lucro. Está bom e fim de conversa.

Quem pode dizer se está indo bem ou não é a administração da rede SO. Pois mesmo com números razoavelmente bons, não quer dizer nada. Há muitos sites com o triplo de acessos e 10 vezes mais usuários mas que não conseguem monetizar nada devido a má gestão.

Nenhum empresário mantém um negócio que não dá lucro. Se isso aqui estivesse indo mal, já teria fechado ou teriam modificado a estratégia para encontrar alguma solução que ao menos cubra o capital inicial.

## Demandas localizadas

Comunidades localizadas são necessárias e possuem uma relevante demanda.

Há diversas questões e discussões que são melhor discutidas numa comunidade localizada.

Exemplo, imagine uma pergunta sobre CEPs ou CPF, CNPJ, etc no SO-en.

Brasileiros que frequentam o SO-en poderiam responder, mas seriam questões localizadas, específicas para modelos de negócios do Brasil e totalmente irrelevante para outras localidades.

Não trata-se apenas do idioma, mas também de questões locais e, isso inclui aspectos culturais e econômicos.

Comment: Achei bem interessante a parte das "demandas localizadas".