# Deve-se usar StackOverflow ou SOpt para fazer perguntas?

Tags: debate, internacionalização

O StackOverflow em Português tem muito menos atividade do que o em Inglês, o que faz sentido, viso que falam mais pessoas inglês do que português.

Mas por exemplo, alguém como eu, que lê e escreve bem nas duas línguas, deveria usar preferencialmente StackOverflow ou SOpt? Eu prefiro o original, porque tem mais atividade, e não uso tanto o SOpt, o que o faz ter ainda menos atividade. Acho que isto se torna um ciclo vicioso.

Então, em casos como o meu, deve-se usar StackOverflow em Inglês ou em Português?

Comment: Você praticamente já respondeu sua pergunta. No meu caso, sou ruim em inglês, então prefiro o SOpt. Mas claro que você pode pensar como uma comunidade BR, com intuito de ajudar quem tem dificuldades e não fala inglês (como eu). Acho que tudo é válido já que o objetivo é ajudar, tirar dúvidas. Muitas vezes tem perguntas no SOpt, que tem respostas no SO.

Comment: Salvos uns contras que tenho aqui, eu ainda vejo o sopt como uma alternativa ao SOEn que eu nao preciso me preocupar se o tradutor está certo ou errado, já é dificil pra caramba elaborar uma pergunta no meu idioma, imagina traduzi-la sem saber o ingles? Se voce sabe ingles, vc pode continuar participando do outro e aqui, pense nisso como forma de fazer a comunidade BR crescer a um ponto em que o conteudo aqui se torne tao vasto e tenha tantas pessoas ativas quanto ao SO em ingles.

Comment: Pois é, não da pra comparar um site internacional que diferentes países acessam com um site que no máximo 5 países de idioma nativo (ou usado informalmente) acessem, não concorda? No nível de quem fala português eu creio que nossos números são satisfatórios, temos respostas pra muitas coisas e posso concluir que talvez a ***sua participação*** é que ainda seja pouca, não estou lhe criticando, estou querendo dizer que talvez você não note a movimentação da comunidade por participar pouco, veja esta postagem com números: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5655/3635 - seja bem vindo!